# Highlight selected link on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'am searching for highlight selected link on the same page using css or javascript or jquery, found many solutions but they are not working according to my requirement.
follwoing are requirement.
Highlight the selected link or change its color etc.

```
<a href="#">First</a>
<a href="#">Second</a>
<a href="#">Third</a>
```

most of the people say to use

```
a:active{
 background-color:Red;
}
or 
a:visited{
 background:color:Red;
}
```

i know ative link is that which is currently active and visited link is that which you already visited.
but they are not working in my case, i am loading the content of same page on click of these links.
any idea how i can do this
Thanks in advance

Comment: By selected link, do you mean a link that has been clicked or a link that you hover the cursor on, or maybe one that has tab focus?

Comment: Selected link mean that link which is currently clicked

Comment: a:hover is totally different from it. i'am looking for active link

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with inline Javascript, like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.style.color='red'">Link</a>
```

You can also trigger a function on the link's click event all with jQuery:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active");
    // define the styles for the active class for this to work
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid code:

```
a:active{
background-color:Red;
}
or 
a:visited{
background:color:Red;
}
```

In addition, they both are trying to set the same color (although the visited link is coded wrong.)

Proper code would be:

```
a:visited, a:active{
background-color: red;
}
```

This will change any links which have been clicked to have a red background, as well as apply a red background to any link when it is in the processes of being clicked.

Comment: Ok but it doesn't work fine and one thing more i already explain that change color in blue or gray it doesn't matter. The problem is it doesn't work on the same page read my Question carefully.

Comment: Sorry, you simply may not be describing things well enough. Are you dynamically loading new links and want those seen as visited? To set the colors, just change "red" to whatever color you want.

Comment: yes loading dynamically but the loading content is same for all link. i found many solution for differnt content but did'nt found any solution for same content

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_active look at this example. i'am working in asp.net and i found the problem was his Doctype  <DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">